# Multiple Propel Like Filters

Tags: php, symfony, propel

Trying to filter a column by multiple conditions using LIKE.

Like this:

```
$d = ItemQuery::create()
                ->filterByName($array_of_names, Criteria::LIKE)
                ->find();
```

But I get "Array to string conversion in propel/src/Propel/Runtime/Connection/StatementWrapper.php"

**How can I filter by multiple "names" using the "LIKE" criteria?**

I basically want the query to be

`...name LIKE %name1% OR name LIKE %name2% OR name LIKE %name2%...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$array_of_names` is `[$name1, $name2, ...]`

```
$q = ItemQuery::create()

foreach ($array_of_names as $i => $name) {
    if ($i > 0) { // Not the first item in the array
        $q->_or();
    }

    $q->where('Item.Name LIKE %?%', $name);
}

$d = $q->find();
```

See

http://propelorm.org/blog/2012/03/20/don-t-do-this-at-home-5-use-where-instead-of-filterby.html

and

http://propelorm.org/blog/2011/02/21/using-or-in-propel-queries-becomes-much-easier-with-propel-1-6.html

or

https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/120

Comment: Perfect - thanks! - Also ->filterByName($names, Criteria::LIKE) works here too, instead of where()